# Result of 3072*0.114166238877481?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, math

I'm trying to get the value of `3072*0.114166238877481` and I'm getting different result from different methods.

- I tried with Nodejs= `3072*0.114166238877481` returns
  `350.7186858316216`
- PHP gives up `350.7186858316216` after `precision=17` in php.ini.
- If i increase any more then it spits out a totally different value
  like    `350.718685831621599`.
- From my Windows 10 (or Ubuntu 16.04 and Centos 6) built in calculator
  (standard mode) I get the same result.
- Also tried some online java compilers which also gives the same
  result

However, with Windows 10 built in calculator(Scientific mode) I get `350.718685831621632` which is the expected result. 
How do I get the expected value from Nodejs or with PHP

Comment: See the [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension.

Comment: Used BCMath but the result was 350.7186858316216135 again not matching with expected result.